# Regulate max speed of UITableView scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCells inside of a tableview which perform some fairly chunky graphics programming - I don't want the scrolling to be too fast because it's compute-intensive. Anyone know if there a (public) API mechanism that would enable be to regulate the maximum speed of scrolling of a UITableView?

Comment: You probably need to re-think your approach. Deliberately preventing the user from quickly scrolling the tableview sounds like a really bad user experience.

Comment: agreed. I'll detect speed of scrolling and disable tableviewcell updates if scrolling is too fast.

Comment: Paging Concept for tableview cell ?